# Why is MOSS 2007 Farm level back up not working?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am taking entire Farm level back up using Central Administration > Operations > Perform a Backup   , but it is getting stuck at one point and the timer job is not getting completed.

When i looked at the Log file , i found following details

"The previous instance of the timer job '**Application Server Timer Job**', id '{7E1EE263-26BA-4412-9F93-E5FC58F53EAD}' for service '{5417B700-85A6-4431-B6CC-92F7CA4FED86}' is still running, so the current instance will be skipped.  Consider increasing the interval between jobs."

on Central Administration > Operations > Timer Job Status   page i am seeing both "Application Server Timer Job " and "Backup/Restore" job status as initialized but with 0 % completion.

I even tried to perform back up using stsadm command, but that did not help.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the issue got resolved after installing WSS 3.O SP2 and MOSS 2OO7 SP2.